# "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element" error on <body> tag

Tags: html, css, xml

I am trying to check if my html is a well formed xml as well but I am keep getting this error on the body tag,

```
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: location/index.xml
Line Number 10, Column 1:
<body>
^
```

And here is the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <header>
        </header>

        <nav >

        </nav>
        <article>

        </article>
    </main>

        <div class="push"></div>

        <footer>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Whhy am I getting this error ?

Comment: XML should have `<html>` tag at the top (after doctype). You close this tag, but don't open that.

Comment: In HTML the start tag for the html element is optional. XML makes all tags required.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to start with an `html` tag. The `head` element is taken as a root element and there is a junk (`body`) after this root element (just children, not siblings of root are allowed).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> <!-- here -->
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <main>
        <header>
        </header>

        <nav >

        </nav>
        <article>

        </article>
        </main>

        <div class="push"></div>

        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```