# Blog post cards |safe whithout styling?

Tags: django

On my blog post cards I have truncated text of the post previewed. I create the posts with with ckeditor so my problem is when I create a post if I have `|safe` used on the cards it renders with large text or any styling.

Is there any way I can just have plain text while using safe to not show tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can add a method in your model to render those strings without the html tags. For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Post(models.Model):
   ...
   
   @property
   def plain_text(self):
       return ''.join(ET.fromstring(self.content).itertext())
```

Then use it in template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.plain_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am using python module [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from removing html tags, so you do not need to use `|safe`.

### Update

You can try the following solution with regex:

```
import re
html_tags_re = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

class Post(models.Model):
   # rest of the code...

   @property
   def plain_text(self):
       return html_tags_re.sub('', self.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So I tried  `{{ post.plain_text.content }}` (hopefully that's right) and I got `junk after document element: line 3, column 0`

Comment: no need to use `.content` after `plain_text`, because `plain_text` is a string

Comment: Okay I fixed that but I still get `junk after document element: line 3, column 0`

Comment: I think the html structures are not right. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533624/xml-parsing-error-junk-after-document-element-error-on-body-tag I am going to update the answer soon with an alternative solution